# Best practice to use urn namespace in rdf

Tags: sparql, rdf, uuid, semantic-web, urn

**TLDR:** What is the best practice to use `urn` namespace?

**Full Context:**

Hi,

I want to create a class with a data property that has `urn:uuid` as range, so did some research on what is the best practice to use `urn` namespace. The purpose is to represent identifier.

When I use the `urn` namespace in Jena Fuseki, it automatically creates the prefix: `PREFIX urn: <http://fliqz.com/>`.

However, when I accessed `http://fliqz.com`, it didn't seem related to the `urn` namespace.

Therefore, I look into the [RFC 8141: Uniform Resource Names (URNs)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8141.html#section-2.1), but found no specifications for the prefix declaration. Though, it claims:

> A Uniform Resource Name (URN) is a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI)
> that is assigned under the "urn" URI scheme and **a particular URN
> namespace**, with the intent that the URN will be a persistent,
> location-independent resource identifier.

I expected something like `PREFIX urn: <http://fliqz.com/>` from the [RFC 8141](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8141.html#section-2.1).

The question [What is the intended way to reference a URN in RDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055715/what-is-the-intended-way-to-reference-a-urn-in-rdf) is the most similar question, but the answer treats `urn` as naming convention of `rdf:resource`. It mentioned [RDF/XML Syntax Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-rdf-syntax/), but the document does not have specification regarding `urn`.

What is the best practice to use `urn` namespace?

Thanks!

---

**Edit 1 for [@AndyS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/757100/andys)**

Thank you for helping me out! This is Jena Fuseki SPARQL GUI on empty graph database and when I type `urn:` namespace, it immediately adds `PREFIX urn: <http://fliqz.com/>` above.

[image: Jena Fuseki URN namespace]

Comment: Please provide more information about "When I use the urn namespace in Jena Fuseki, it automatically creates the prefix: PREFIX urn: <http://fliqz.com/>." Namespaces come from the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The misunderstanding is that `urn:` identifies an RDF namespace ‒ it does not, it is a URI scheme, like `http`. In Turtle or SPARQL, you would use the URI syntax, like `<urn:uuid:29d82556-7fac-4ab8-b1a1-a652d4b1ee36>`. Typing `urn:` seems to confuse the GUI which tries to look for a commonly used prefix with this name.

It just so happened that [prefix.cc](http://prefix.cc/) [used to](http://web.archive.org/web/20220520172837/http://prefix.cc/urn) have a URI prefix defined for `urn:`, which seems to have been removed only recently. I suppose the Jena GUI had it cached.

If you want to define a prefix to be used, you can use `PREFIX urn: <urn:>` or even `PREFIX uuid: <urn:uuid:>`.

Comment: Wow, I got enlightenment! Thank you so much!

Comment: Good answer from IS4.

It's an older version of Fuseki and an older version of yasgui (the UI looks different in recent versions).

Comment: @AndyS Thank you for the triangulation! I wouldn't know I was also using an old version of Fuseki.

Comment: For others who use older version of Fuseki like me, I built Jena Fuseki 4.7.0 Docker image based on stain/jena-fuseki Dockerfile: https://hub.docker.com/r/leroykim/jena-fuseki-4.7.0